# .NET Core 6 SQL Server connection without Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-6.0

I am new to .NET Core. I have defined the connection string in `appsettings.json` like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestBD": "Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

I am not using Entity Framework. I need to connect to the database using this connection string from the `Program.cs` file.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` etc. classes from ADO.NET in .NET 6 - no problem. There are **tons** of resources showing you how to do this exactly. Make use of the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` nuget package - see [this article](https://www.thatsoftwaredude.com/content/11497/taking-a-look-at-microsoftdatasqlclient-in-net-core) as a starting point

Answer (score 8):

You refer the following sample code to use ADO.NET in Asp.net 6 program.cs:

```
//required using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
app.MapGet("/movies", () =>
{
    var movies = new List<Movie>();
    //to get the connection string 
    var _config = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    var connectionstring = _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    //build the sqlconnection and execute the sql command
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        conn.Open();  
        string commandtext = "select MovieId, Title, Genre from Movie";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conn); 

        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var movie = new Movie()
            {
                MovieId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieId"]),
                Title = reader["Title"].ToString(),
                Genre = reader["Genre"].ToString()
            };

            movies.Add(movie);
        } 
    }
    return movies;
});
```

The result like this:

[image]