# Multiple Connection Strings in .NET 6 without using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webapi

I am new to .NET Core, so forgive me if my question is so basic.
I always use .NET Framework for my all project, but now I have to move to .NET Core 6.
In .NET Framework, I set my connection string in Web.config like this:

```
<add key="ConnStr" value="Data Source=DESKTOP-854AIA7;Initial Catalog=TestOTA;User ID=sa;Password=1"/>
    <add key="ConnStrReport" value="Data Source=192.168.5.226;Initial Catalog=cachrsp01;User ID=sa;Password=123@123"/>
    <add key="ConnStrLog" value="Data Source=192.168.5.226;Initial Catalog=loghrsp01;User ID=sa;Password=123@123"/>
```

then I have a class to manage them like this :

```
public class AccessToDb{
     public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string tmp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStr"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
            {
                do something
                
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    public static string ConnectionStringLog
    {
        get
        {
            string tmp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStrLog"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
            {
                do something
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

In other classes when I need to call them, depends on which one I need I call them like:

```
 objSqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(AccessToDb.ConnectionString);
```

or

```
 objSqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(AccessToDb.ConnectionStringLog);
```

But I don't know where to set my Connection string and where to call them and how to use it in my methods. I search but all results I found, used entity framework.

---

**UPDATE**

I checked and finally find a way around it. I add this in appsettings.json :

```json
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "mymainDB": "server=192.168.5.226;database=cachrsp01;user id=sa;password='123@123'",
        "myLogDB": "server=192.168.5.226;database=loghrsp01;user id=sa;password='123@123'"
    }
}
```

then I created Class AccessToDb like this:

```
public class AccessToDb
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static string ConnectionStringLog { get; set; }
}
```

Finally in Program.cs I configure them:

```
AccessToDb.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("mymainDB");
AccessToDb.ConnectionStringLog = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myLogDB");
```

everything now works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260908/net-core-6-sql-server-connection-without-entity-framework) will help you.

Comment: @QingGuo thanks but It is not what I mean